# How to open Desktop directory from Cygwin?

Tags: windows-8.1, cygwin, desktop

I am newbie in **Cygwin**, In windows, **command prompt** I used **Cd Desktop** command to move to the Desktop but when I using this same command for Cygwin it shows the following error

`-bash: cd: Desktop: No such file or directory`

Why is this error showing?
And how to go to the Desktop from Cygwin?

Comment: what is your current working path? type pwd

Comment: I installed Cygwin on C drive and there is a Home folder in the Cygwin64 folder and that is the default path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is no directory named `Desktop` in your current directory. Linux have a little different philosophy, and you can't get to `Desktop` in this way from every place. You can get instead into **home** directory by typing `cd ~` from every place and to **root** directory by typing `cd /` from every place -> you can think about it in that way, that Linux uses home directory instead of Desktop. Every other time you have to `cd` to **absolute path** (which starts with `/`) or **relative path** (which starts with `./` or with no character).

Example:

1. You are in directory /home/ninja (you can get your current directory by typing `pwd`).
2. You type `ls`. Console logs all directories which you can get into now by typing `cd`. E.g console logged: `Download Documents Music`, so you can type now `cd Download` to move there.
3. Additionally no matter where you currently are, you can use `cd /` and `cd ~`

Try that. ;)

Comment: I can't understand it clearly plz give a example

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. While this explains how you can navigate in cygwin, does not really tell you where exactly you can find your Desktop directory on your Windows filesystem. The answer by @Baldrickk is more accurate

Answer (score 6):

By default, your cygwin home directory is under `C:\cygwin\home`
Your Windows home directory is under `C:\Users\`

Cygwin doesn't use the same root path as Windows does.  The path to a drive is:

```
\cygdrive\DRIVE_ID
```

where `DRIVE_ID` is the lowercase windows drive letter.

So your desktop is located at:

```
\cygdrive\c\Users\coding_ninza\Desktop
```

assuming of course that your username is `coding_ninza` and you have the usual `C:` drive.

```
cd \cygdrive\c\Users\coding_ninza\Desktop
```

will get you to your Windows desktop from any other directory.  You can of course use relative paths to navigate too.

Comment: Cygwin/POSIX uses forward slashes for paths, not back-slashes.  I think cygwin permits either, because Windows, but forward would be more proper for a POSIX environment.

Answer (score 6):

Very Simple, don't be confused type;

```
cd C:/Users/Your_Username/Desktop
```

And it takes you to that Directory as Simple as that.

**Cygwin Output**

[image: Cygwin output]

Enjoy>>>

Comment: It worked for me in Cygwin, have you tried it. My Version 2.004 (Latest)

Comment: Ah, my bad then, sorry. Please edit your answer to explicitly add that, and some Cygwin output?

Comment: @Arjan Done it you can see

Answer (score 0):

### Maybe this command can help you:

Open the cygwin shortcut on the desktop as an administrator.

---

endi@endi-PC ~
$ cd c:/

endi@endi-PC /cygdrive/c
$ cd c:/xampp

endi@endi-PC /cygdrive/c/xampp
$ cd c:/xampp/htdocs

endi@endi-PC /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs
$

---

[this is what I did to open the xampp / htdocs folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8M13.png)

Comment: Why would an unnecessarily complicated way to change to htdocs help to get to the Desktop?